# ScrollTrigger match media

Tags: javascript, gsap, matchmedia, scrolltrigger

I have the following match media code, and for some reason, it's being stricken off in JS. Why is it so?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbDXD.png)

Comment: Please, do not post image of code. It would be easier to give you an answer, if you posted some code showing the error here, and also more useful for future users. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Also, try to create a minimal reproducible example, showing not all of your code. That way you're more likely to receive answers, since people won't to navigate into intricacy of your code to try to understand it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example